# I'm not sure if the coordinate descent method for solving this non-convex problem will converge

Tags: non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the non-convex problem.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P1}:  &\max \limits_{x, y} U = -xy\log_2(y)-x^3y^6- xy^2 e^{xy^2},\\
{\rm{s}}.{\rm{t}}.~~& (a) 0 < x \leq X^{max}, \\
& (b) 0 < y \leq Y^{max}, \\
& (c) 0 < xy^2 \leq W^{max}, \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $X^{max}, Y^{max}$, and $W^{max}$ are the maximum of $x$, $y$, and $xy^2$, respectively.

The following conclusion may be true. 
When $y$ is fixed, $\mathbf{P1}$ can be converted into a classical concave optimization problem in terms of $x$, which is denoted as $\mathbf{P2}$. Similarly, when $x$ is fixed, $\mathbf{P1}$ can be also converted into a classical concave optimization problem in terms of $y$, which is denoted as $\mathbf{P3}$.

Based on the conclusion, there are two methods.

(1) The first method：

A coordinate descent method is adopted to solve $\mathbf{P2}$ and $\mathbf{P3}$ alternately until the algorithm converges.

(2) The second method:

When $y$ is fixed, we can set $\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{ x }}=0$ and obtain an implicit expression, i.e., $- y\log_2(y) - 3x^2 y^6 - y^2 e^{xy^2} - xy^4 e^{xy^2} = 0$. Based on the implicit expression, I can obtain $\hat{x}^{\star} = \hat{x}^{\star}(y)$. 
Combining the constraints (b) and (c) in $\mathbf{P1}$, and $\hat{x}^{\star}(y)$, we can obtain $x^{\star}(y)=\min \left\{\hat{x}^{\star}(y), X^{max}, \frac{W^{max}}{y^2} \right\}$.
Substitute $x^{\star}(y)$ into the optimization problem $\mathbf{P1}$, and all $x$ is removed from the optimization problem $\mathbf{P1}$, which becomes 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P4}:  &\max \limits_{y} U = -x^{\star}(y) y\log_2(y)-x^{\star}(y)^3y^6- x^{\star}(y)y^2 e^{x^{\star}(y)y^2},\\
{\rm{s}}.{\rm{t}}.~~& (a) 0 < y \leq Y^{max}, \\
& (b) 0 < x^{\star}(y) y^2 \leq W^{max}. \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I can use a greedy algorithm to solve $\mathbf{P4}$, and obtain $y^{\star}$. Via $x^{\star}(y)=\min \left\{\hat{x}^{\star}(y), X^{max}, \frac{W^{max}}{y^2} \right\}$, we can obtain $x^{\star}(y^{\star})$.

For the above two methods, I have the following two questions. 
Firstly, I am not sure if these two methods are correct. Secondly, I'm not sure if the first method will converge.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first method (CD) will convergence since the problem is concave in term of $x$ and $y$ respectively. But I don't understand the difference between these two method, it seems that **P4** is also concave problem, why you need a greedy algorithm?

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your suggestion.

Why you need a greedy algorithm?

With $\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{ x }}=0$, I can only obtain an implicit expression about $x$ and $y$. The implicit expression makes it impossible to obtain a closed-form solution of $x$, Thus, the convexity of the objective function and constraints in $\mathbf{P4}$ may not be analyzed.